# In java regex replace \ by " ignore if forward slash / followed by backward slash \ is there

Tags: java, regex

In Java using RegEx I am replacing \ by ". But if I wanted only one `\ backward slash` is found replace by `"(double quote)` , but if `forward slash(/)` followed by `backward slash(\)` replace  replace only forward slash keep the backward slash as it is.

code replace function `.replaceAll("\\\\", "\"")`

Example: if only one backward slash found

```
input:  Functions.split(input.env.companyId,\"\\\")"
output: Functions.split(input.env.companyId,""")
```

If `forward slash(/)` followed by `backward slash(\)` replace  replace only forward slash keep the backward slash as it is.

```
input: Functions.split(input.env.companyId,\"/\\\")
ouput: Functions.split(input.env.companyId,"\")
```

So, combining the expected output of both cases how to get expected output by modifying the replaceAll regex pattern.

Comment: Can I ask what the context is here? A lot of the time when I see questions like this, it's for parsing a well-known data format like JSON or CSV - in which case it's generally better to use a library which has been specifically written for the task. That may not be the case here, but I thought it worth checking.

Comment: If input is text value `...,\"\\\")"`, and you only replace a standalone ``\`` with `"`, then only the first ``\`` is to be replaced, resulting in `...,""\\\")"`, which is not the `...,""")` you claim you want. Please clarify!

Comment: sorry I have changed the question, I wanted to replace \ by " but if forward slash / followed by backward slash is there  ,replace forward slash rest of the the keep as it is

Comment: @vikram You still didn't clarify. If actual input **text value** is `...,\"\\\")"` *(the actual text value, i.e. the result text after Java compiler has unescaped a string literal in whatever form it took)*, with 4 ``\`` and 3 `"`, and you never replace `"`, and you sometimes(?) replace ``\`` with `"` and sometimes(?) replace `/` with `"`, and otherwise leave ``\`` and `/` alone, then result would have same number of characters, so why do you expect result `...,""")` where all the ``\`` are gone, and the last `"` has somehow moved before the `)`? It makes no sense at all. Please clarify!!

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*This answer is currently for [version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59808523/2) of the question. Awaiting clarifications before attempting to update to fit latest version.*</sup>

Use negative lookarounds to find `\` that is not preceded or followed by `\`, i.e. to find standalone `\` characters in the input string.

*Example*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("Functions.split(input.env.companyId,\\\"\\\\\\\")\"");
}
static void test(String input) {
    String output = input.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\)", "\"");
    System.out.println("input:  " + input);
    System.out.println("output: " + output);
}
```

*Output*

```
input:  Functions.split(input.env.companyId,\"\\\")"
output: Functions.split(input.env.companyId,""\\\")"
```

Comment: @vikram Please notice the big difference between the **input text**, as printed, and the *string literal* in the `main` method needed to produce that input text. Your question is showing *input text* and output text, not *string literals*. Please be clear on the difference between the *text* and the *literal* needed to produce that *text* when you clarify the question as I've repeatedly requested.